# Is possible to change JetBrains IDE editor background color by scope/folder

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, goland

**Problem:**

I'm working on a modular project where different folders represents different components of the application. I want to identify where I'am easily.

**My idea:**

I created two scopes for the components folders, and I set different colours to them:
[image]
[image]

**Question:**

It would be nice to be able to change the background color of the text editor too and not only the tabs, and project explorer.

Is it possible to do it with any plugin or script?
Is there any other way to identify in which module I'm?

Comment: Have you tried to enable _Always Select Opened File_ option? It is under Project View settings (gear icon left from `helpers.go` file on your screenshot).

Comment: 1) You have the color already in the Editor tab -- it's a good enough indication. 2) Using the aforementioned "Always Select Opened File" option can also help (although I personally do not like such behaviour). 3) I know none of such plugins. 4) The most close ticket that I have faced thus far (no the same but related): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106958 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66312

Comment: P.S. There are plugins that allow assigning custom colors to different files without using a scope (see https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13951-projecttree-color-highlighter)  ... but nothing I can think of that would do this for the editor background (as normally ppl want to have the "editor working area" to be in a consistent state). But you can try this one: it adds a coloured strip at the top of the editor that states the module this file belongs to. Not sure if it can work with custom scopes or folders though (or in GoLand): https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18928-module-colors

Comment: Sadly there's no way to use the scope color for the editor. In addition to the editor tab color and selecting the current file in the Project view you could also use the Navigation bar (enabled in View > Appearance > Navigation bar) to see what module the current file belongs to.